# stashing variables?

Tags: templating, variable

I have an entry id in that I am storing in a variable that I would like to access outside of this for statement, is there a way I can "stash" it somewhere? I want to do another query based on tags but make sure I exclude this entry id.

```
{% for entry in manualPost.all() %}

    {% set manualPostID = entry.id %}

    {% if entry.blogHero|length %}

        {% set optimizedImages = entry.blogHero.one().optimizedimages %}

        <a href="{{ entry.url }}"><img src="{{ optimizedImages.src() }}"srcset="{{ optimizedImages.srcset() }}"sizes="100vw" /></a>

    {% endif %}

    <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twig doesn't let you stash variables for access elsewhere; rather every variable has a well defined scope. So what you'd have to do is store that `id` in a variable that has a global context, so other templates you `include` can access it.

See the [Twig Processing Order & Scope](https://nystudio107.com/blog/twig-processing-order-and-scope) article for more info on this.